# Bitcoin Withdrawl

Tags: blockchain, fraud

I’ve been contacted by Bridgeway Consult after losing money previously on Forex with a company. I’ve been told my details have been used to hold bitcoin in my name by various people and have been sent a link with my ‘personal hash’ with proof of funds to the current value on blockchain website . In order to release I ‘need to increase the activity of my recently created wallet‘ to fully verify and receive the amount. The updates are coming from security@cryptosupport.agency is this a scam ?

Comment: Yes, this is most definitely a scam.

Comment: 100% typical scam.